# make other class frame setvisible(false) when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to make other class frame setvisible(false) when button is pressed.

There is a class called DisplayScore and this class gets getContentPane().add(new ScoreInfo()); from ScoreInfo class.
Reason for spliting into two class is because DisplayScore extends JFrame and ScoreInfo extends JPanel.
Anyway

In ScoreInfo when button is pressed I want to call up other frame and close the DisplayScore frame. If I do this.setVisible(false);, only the Panel disappear, and the frame which is made from DisplayScore(), remains.

So..my question is how handle that from ScoreInfo class? 
Check out the buttom part. actionPerformed method.

```
public class ScoreInfo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
        JButton btnBack;

public ScoreInfo()
{


    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    ta.setForeground(Color.white);
    ta.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, 16));
    ta.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    try
    {
        ta.read(new FileReader("data/scores4.txt"),null);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.print("ERROR: Could not read file \"");
    }


    btnBack = new JButton("MAIN");
    btnBack.setSize(10,10);
    btnBack.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, 15));
    btnBack.setForeground(Color.black);

    JPanel score = new JPanel();
    score.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton btnScore = new JButton("H I G H  S C O R E");
    btnScore.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnScore.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, 48));
    btnScore.setForeground(Color.white);

    JLabel score_tab = new JLabel("   N A M E  " + "  S C O R E  " + "  C O M B O  ");
    score_tab.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, 35));


    score.add(btnBack, BorderLayout.WEST);
    score.add(btnScore, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    score.add(score_tab, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 380));
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(score, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //panel.add(backpnl, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel, score);

    btnBack.addActionListener(this);

    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    if(evt.getSource()==btnBack){

        //want to make DisplayScore.setVisible(false); 
        //this.setVisible(false);
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        mf.pack();
        mf.setSize(640,480);
        mf.setLocation(400,0);
        mf.setResizable(false);
        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mf.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) The pop-up GUI might be best done as a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`. 3) *"because DisplayScore extends JFrame.."*  Don't extend frame.  *"..and ScoreInfo extends JPanel"*  ..or panel.  Instead simply create one and add things to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Pass a reference of the parent frame to the panel.  I think this is a little dirty, but that's just me.
- Use [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29) to find the parent window of the current component.  You can then call `setVisible` on it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if(evt.getSource()==btnBack){

    getParent.setVisible(false);
    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
```

But is not too robust, since you can't know if the parent is actually the `JFrame` ( and as MadProgrammer commented, this would be the contentPane, so this won't work). A better approach would be to ask for the `JFrame` in the constructor, and hide it necessarily.

Comment: `getParent` is likely to be the content pane of the `JFrame` (or `JDialog`)